# How to get Swagger to send API key as a http instead of in the URL

Tags: javascript, servicestack, swagger

I am using swagger with [servicestack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) but I am getting a 401 unauthorised error from my /resources URL becuase it requires an API key.

Unless I'm mistaken, [according to the documentation](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui) I should set *supportHeaderParams* to true as well as the *apiKeyName* and *apiKey* value in the JSON parameters when initializing Swagger from my html page.

I was then expecting to see my API key in the http request headers, but it is still being appended to the URL and not in the headers collection.

Here is the code that initialises Swagger in my HTML page:

```
 window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
            discoveryUrl: "http://pathtomyservice.com/resources",
                headers: { "testheader" : "123" },
                apiKey: "123",
                apiKeyName: "Api-Key",
                dom_id:"swagger-ui-container",
                supportHeaderParams: true,
                supportedSubmitMethods: ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'],
                onComplete: function(swaggerApi, swaggerUi){
                    if(console) {
                        console.log("Loaded SwaggerUI");
                        console.log(swaggerApi);
                        console.log(swaggerUi);
                    }
                  $('pre code').each(function(i, e) {hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
                },
                onFailure: function(data) {
                    if(console) {
                        console.log("Unable to Load SwaggerUI");
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                },
                docExpansion: "none"
            });
```

Unfortunately I get no headers at all, no 'Api-Key' or 'testheader'.

Comment: the same issue for me...

Comment: I guess this is related to swagger (http://goo.gl/kMHNz) but I still don't know how to fix it in servicestack

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think that it might be a bug in swagger ui.

As a workaround, I added the following in in the swagger index.html file.

```
$(function () {
   $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
           jqXHR.setRequestHeader("YourApiKeyHeader", $("#input_apiKey").val());
       }
   });
});
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: You might want to look at the new version of swagger-ui - 1.3. _supportHeaderParams_ isn't needed anymore.

Comment: How to set #input_apiKey  value for dynamically generated key?. I am struggling for that from 2 days. Please help me out. Also posted question in S.O.    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435286/swagger-ui-passing-authentication-token-to-api-call-in-header

Comment: This adds the value to the header but it doesn't remove it from the url.  I'd like to add my own authentication header using the api_key entered but I don't want the api_key sent in get or post.  Still working out this solution myself but I'm curious if anyone here worked that out.

Answer (score 20):

In swagger-ui 2.0 or greater, this is trivial:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui#header-parameters

```
// add a new ApiKeyAuthorization when the api-key changes in the ui.
$('#input_apiKey').change(function() {
  var key = $('#input_apiKey')[0].value;
  if(key && key.trim() != "") {
    window.authorizations.add("key", new ApiKeyAuthorization("api_key", key, "header"));
  }
})
```

This is also much more extensible and supports custom authentication mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I didn't know there was a v2.0 released, I will definitely take a look. Cheers

Comment: How to set #input_apiKey  value for dynamically generated key?. I am struggling for that from 2 days. Please help me out. Also Posted question in S.O.        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33435286/swagger-ui-passing-authentication-token-to-api-call-in-header

Comment: This doesn't work still. Any addition to headers with window.authorizations.add() or window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add() does not have any effect and Authorisation header is not added.

Comment: I'm quite positive that it works.  Can you please share how you're testing it?

Comment: @JavaP Once you have the token you can set it in api_key on swaggerUI home page. So again if a new token is generated then you have to set it in home page one more time. But one suggestion I can give, Swagger UI source code is available so you can customize as per your requirement. Definitely you can try to whats your requirement is.

Comment: for me its also not working, is there something i need to define in my API yaml for server?

Comment: You have to declare what needs to be authenticated inside your swagger definition.  If it's everything, then there should be a `security` element at the top-level.  In addition, there was a recent update to swagger-ui which dynamically shows authentication mechanisms.  See a demo at http://petstore.swagger.io or grab from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui in the master branch

Comment: Is there a section for "header-parameters" in the `swagger-ui` github page? I don't see it. The link should be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        var basicAuthUI =
                '<div class="input"><input placeholder="username" id="input_username" name="username" type="text" size="10"/></div>' +
                '<div class="input"><input placeholder="password" id="input_password" name="password" type="password" size="10"/></div>';
        $(basicAuthUI).insertBefore('#api_selector div.input:last-child');
        $("#input_apiKey").hide();

        $('#input_username').change(addAuthorization);
        $('#input_password').change(addAuthorization);
    });

    function addAuthorization() {
        SwaggerApi.supportHeaderParams = true;
        SwaggerApi.headers = {"authentication": "test"};
        var username = $('#input_username').val();
        var password = $('#input_password').val();
        if (username && username.trim() != "" && password && password.trim() != "") {
            var basicAuth = new SwaggerClient.PasswordAuthorization('basic', username, password);
            window.swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("basicAuth", basicAuth);
            console.log("authorization added: username = " + username + ", password = " + password);
        }
    }
})();
```