# Swagger UI passing authentication token to API call in header

Tags: rest, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am new to Swagger.

I am using Swagger UI to generate swagger documentation. I have two API calls. First call is to generate token based on user name and password. Second call needs token generated by first call.

How I set that token for second call using Swagger UI?

Comment: Will try and let you know

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[`@ApiImplicitParams`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParams.html) and [`@ApiImplicitParam`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html) should do the trick:

```java
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
@ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization", value = "Authorization token", 
                      required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header") })
public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String userName) {
    ...
}
```

From the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations-1.5.X#apiimplicitparam-apiimplicitparams):

> You may wish you describe operation parameters manually. This can be for various reasons, for example:
>
> - Using Servlets which don't use JAX-RS annotations.
> - Wanting to hide a parameter as it is defined and override it with a completely different definition.
> - Describe a parameter that is used by a filter or another resource prior to reaching the JAX-RS implementation.

The Swagger UI will be updated so you can send your token from there. No changes to HTML will be necessary.

---

<sub>**Note:** A while ago, when documenting a REST API with Swagger, I realized that just adding [`@ApiImplicitParam`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParam.html) is not enough (even if you have only one parameter). Anyway, you must add [`@ApiImplicitParams`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiImplicitParams.html) too.</sub>

Comment: how to get token from POST /oauth/token by adding parameters like username, password and grant type? because in swagger UI only parametters node is listed how to add custom parametters there?

Answer (score 8):

My configuration for **2.9.2 Swagger** version to add Authorization on Swagger UI and send the Bearer token

```java
    @Configuration
    public class SwaggerConfiguration{

        //...

          @Bean
          public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) {
            return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)...
                .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(apiKey()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
          }

          private SecurityContext securityContext() {
            return SecurityContext.builder().securityReferences(defaultAuth()).forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build();
          }

          private List<SecurityReference> defaultAuth() {
            final AuthorizationScope authorizationScope = new AuthorizationScope("global", "accessEverything");
            final AuthorizationScope[] authorizationScopes = new AuthorizationScope[]{authorizationScope};
            return Collections.singletonList(new SecurityReference("Bearer", authorizationScopes));
          }

          private ApiKey apiKey() {
            return new ApiKey("Bearer", "Authorization", "header");
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to add `globalOperationParameters`. It will add a field for authorization in every endpoint.

Define authorization header parameter:

```java
Parameter authHeader = new ParameterBuilder()
  .parameterType("header")
  .name("Authorization")
  .modelRef(new ModelRef("string"))
  .build();
```

Add it to `Docket` configuration:

```java
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    .select()
    .apis(...)
    .paths(...)
    .build()
    .apiInfo(...)
    .globalOperationParameters(Collections.singletonList(authHeader));
```

And it will look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is a hack that might work by using responseInterceptor and requestInterceptor

First capture response of the the first API call using `responseInterceptor` and save the token (in the example in local storage), then use `requestInterceptor` to add the `Authorization` header with the saved token.

```
            const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
               ...
                responseInterceptor:
                    function (response) {
                        if (response.obj.access_token) {
                            console.log(response.obj.access_token)
                            const token = response.obj.access_token;
                            localStorage.setItem("token", token)
                        }

                        return response;
                    },
                requestInterceptor:
                    function (request) {
                        console.log('[Swagger] intercept try-it-out request');
                        request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token");
                        return request;
                }
           }
```

Comment: Actually, I just tried this out and the responseInterceptor doesn't seem to be called for the auth-related responses.

Comment: hmm. this might have changed, keep in mind the response is 4 years old, in the meanwhile swagger might have changed the workflow for auth, especially since this might cause auth token leaks.

Comment: yes, so, i found out that now there is an option `persistAuthorization` that when set to `true`, will cause the authorization data to be stored in localStorage. =)

Answer (score 1):

You would have to customise the [swagger index page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/dist/index.html) to accomplish that I believe.

You can make the input 'input_apiKey' hidden and add two inputs for username and password. Then you make an ajax call to update the hidden input with your token.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but this is how I solved it recently with version 2.7.0 for my JWT tokens

In your swagger configuration, add below `SecurityConfiguration` bean. Important part being leaving fifth argument empty or null.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityConfiguration securityInfo() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(null, null, null, null, "", ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER,"Authorization","");
    }
```

Add `securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()))` to your main `Docket` bean.

```
@Bean
    public Docket docket()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .....build().apiInfo(...).securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
    }


    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("Authorization", "Authorization", "header");
    }
```

Then in UI , you need to click on **Authorize** button and input "Bearer  access_token" (for Authorization text box )where **access_token** is token provided by jWT token server.

Once this authorization is saved,that will become effective for all end points. Adding a separate text field for each end point looks very cumbersome.

Comment: Is this specific to Spring project?

Comment: Yes, `Bean` is a Spring concept . Automatic configuration pick up is for Spring Boot. If you have Java config then caller to that config can be non - Spring framework but in this case, it is intended for Spring.

Comment: @SabirKhan How do I implement it without spring-fox? I'm using springdoc-openapi-ui (1.3.2). But still facing same issue. My spring boot version is 2.2.6. Hence needed to remove spring-fox.

Comment: @iaL:I am not sure ,will try to find & let you know if find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using Swagger UI 4, I've done this by configuring [`persistAuthorization`](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/#authorization) and [`requestInterceptor`](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/#network) Swagger UI configuration parameters:

1. setting the `persistAuthorization` to `true` makes it storing the authorization data in browser's `localStorage`
2. adding a `requestInterceptor` JS function that modify requests to pass along the `accept_token`.

Here is what my requestInterceptor function looks like:

```
function(request) {
    let authorize_json = window.sessionStorage.getItem('authorized')
    if (!authorize_json || authorize_json === '{}') {
        authorize_json = window.localStorage.getItem('authorized')
        if (!authorize_json) {
            return request
        }
    }

    // move from localStorage to sessionStorage, for better security
    window.localStorage.removeItem('authorized')
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('authorized', authorize_json)

    const persistedAuthData = JSON.parse(authorize_json)
    if (!persistedAuthData.oauth2) {
        return request
    }
    const access_token = persistedAuthData.oauth2.token.access_token
    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
    return request
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using SpringDoc with the springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin my option is to use a SwaggerConfig.Java:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration  {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI(@Value("${project.version}") String appVersion) {
        OpenAPI openApi = new OpenAPI();
                openApi.info(
                    new Info()
                .title("Title Example")
                .version(appVersion)
                .description("Swagger server created using springdocs - a library for OpenAPI 3 with spring boot.")
                );

                openApi.components(
                        new Components().addSecuritySchemes("bearer-jwt",
                new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT")
                        .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER).name("Authorization"))
                );

                openApi.addSecurityItem(
                        new SecurityRequirement().addList("bearer-jwt", Arrays.asList("read", "write"))
                );

        return openApi;
    }
}
```